# How to get the streaming information of a youtube using python

Tags: python-2.7, youtube

I need to get some data in a youtube link and put it into a log file.
For example, when I reload the web page of youtube while streaming. I want to know how many seconds the video will reload(in my term its the start delay). 2nd the buffering time in seconds and third is the buffering count.

I'm tried this code.

```
os.system("youtube-dl samplelink.com >> log.txt")
```

and it returns a data like this:

```
[youtube] Tjnq5StX68g: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Tjnq5StX68g: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] Tjnq5StX68g: Extracting video information
[youtube] Tjnq5StX68g: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Destination: /youtubeDL/.f134

[download]   0.0% of 5.30MiB at 29.12KiB/s ETA 03:06
[download]   0.1% of 5.30MiB at 84.97KiB/s ETA 01:03
[download]   0.1% of 5.30MiB at 194.16KiB/s ETA 00:27
[download]   0.3% of 5.30MiB at 407.48KiB/s ETA 00:13
[download]   0.6% of 5.30MiB at 283.76KiB/s ETA 00:19
[download]   1.2% of 5.30MiB at 291.57KiB/s ETA 00:18
[download]   2.3% of 5.30MiB at 314.81KiB/s ETA 00:16
[download]   4.7% of 5.30MiB at 304.90KiB/s ETA 00:16
[download]   9.4% of 5.30MiB at 303.54KiB/s ETA 00:16
[download]  15.0% of 5.30MiB at 312.94KiB/s ETA 00:14
[download]  21.1% of 5.30MiB at 319.35KiB/s ETA 00:13
[download]  27.3% of 5.30MiB at 324.89KiB/s ETA 00:12
[download]  33.6% of 5.30MiB at 331.58KiB/s ETA 00:10
[download]  40.3% of 5.30MiB at 335.11KiB/s ETA 00:09
[download]  46.9% of 5.30MiB at 331.14KiB/s ETA 00:08
[download]  52.6% of 5.30MiB at 323.64KiB/s ETA 00:07
[download]  57.6% of 5.30MiB at 317.95KiB/s ETA 00:07
[download]  62.5% of 5.30MiB at 303.29KiB/s ETA 00:06
[download]  66.2% of 5.30MiB at 297.34KiB/s ETA 00:06
[download]  70.3% of 5.30MiB at 289.84KiB/s ETA 00:05
[download]  74.1% of 5.30MiB at 283.57KiB/s ETA 00:04
[download]  77.8% of 5.30MiB at 279.24KiB/s ETA 00:04
[download]  81.8% of 5.30MiB at 278.76KiB/s ETA 00:03
[download]  86.7% of 5.30MiB at 280.26KiB/s ETA 00:02
[download]  92.4% of 5.30MiB at 282.84KiB/s ETA 00:01
[download]  98.5% of 5.30MiB at 285.65KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] 100.0% of 5.30MiB at 286.26KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] 100% of 5.30MiB in 00:18
[download] Destination: /youtubeDL/.f251

[download]   0.0% of 2.99MiB at 34.13KiB/s ETA 01:30
[download]   0.1% of 2.99MiB at 99.64KiB/s ETA 00:30
[download]   0.2% of 2.99MiB at 225.91KiB/s ETA 00:13
[download]   0.5% of 2.99MiB at 473.01KiB/s ETA 00:06
[download]   1.0% of 2.99MiB at 379.24KiB/s ETA 00:08
[download]   2.1% of 2.99MiB at 341.24KiB/s ETA 00:08
[download]   4.1% of 2.99MiB at 312.79KiB/s ETA 00:09
[download]   8.3% of 2.99MiB at 265.26KiB/s ETA 00:10
[download]  15.8% of 2.99MiB at 243.19KiB/s ETA 00:10
[download]  23.1% of 2.99MiB at 237.15KiB/s ETA 00:09
[download]  30.4% of 2.99MiB at 233.35KiB/s ETA 00:09
[download]  37.7% of 2.99MiB at 227.94KiB/s ETA 00:08
[download]  44.4% of 2.99MiB at 224.52KiB/s ETA 00:07
[download]  51.2% of 2.99MiB at 226.00KiB/s ETA 00:06
[download]  58.9% of 2.99MiB at 228.15KiB/s ETA 00:05
[download]  66.8% of 2.99MiB at 224.88KiB/s ETA 00:04
[download]  73.5% of 2.99MiB at 224.39KiB/s ETA 00:03
[download]  80.6% of 2.99MiB at 221.15KiB/s ETA 00:02
[download]  86.9% of 2.99MiB at 222.09KiB/s ETA 00:01
[download]  94.6% of 2.99MiB at 224.02KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] 100.0% of 2.99MiB at 226.88KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] 100% of 2.99MiB in 00:13
[ffmpeg] Merging formats into "/youtubeDL/.mkv"
```